# BaseFieldDefinition setDisplayOptions ... type = 'string_textfield' ... unable to set default placeholder or size?

Tags: 8, entities, plugins

I'm unable to get a default placeholder and/or size to register against a BaseFieldDefinition. I'm trying something like:

```
$fields['company_name'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
      ->setLabel(t('Company Name'))
      ->setDescription(t('What\'s your company called?'))
      ->setDefaultValue('')
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
        'type' => 'string_textfield',
        'settings' => [
          'display_label' => TRUE,
          'size' => 10,
          'placeholder' => '',
        ],
        'weight' => '9',
      ])
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);
```

But when I enable my module, and check the 'Manage Form Display' tab for the relevant entity, it shows the defaults (size = 60, placeholder = {null}).

Does anyone know how to get these working..? Especially the `placeholder` one.

Comment: I think you need to be calling "setSettings" on the field, not passing the settings as a part of the display options.

Answer (score 0):

```
$fields['mobile_number'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
  ->setRevisionable(TRUE)
  ->setLabel(t('Mobile Number'))
  ->setDescription(t('Enter Mobile Number with Country Code.'))
  ->setRequired(TRUE)
  ->setSetting('max_length', 255)
  ->setPropertyConstraints('value', ['Length' => ['max' => 20]])
  ->addPropertyConstraints('value', ['Regex' => ['pattern' => '/^(\+|00)[0-9]+$/']])
  ->addConstraint('UniqueField')
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
    'type' => 'string_textfield',
    'weight' => -5,
    'settings' => [
      'size' => 30,
      'placeholder' => '+919876543210',
    ],
  ])
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
  ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
    'label' => 'above',
    'type' => 'string',
    'weight' => -5,
  ])
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

This works for me.